Find the distribution density of the random variable $X − 2Y$
Random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent. $X$ has a Laplace distribution with density $\frac{1}{2} e^{-|x|}$, and $Y$ – uniform on the interval [1, 2]. Find the distribution density of the random variable $X − 2Y$
I am not sure how to deal with module. What I did:
$F_{\xi}(z) = \int_1^{2}\int_{-\infty}^{z+2y}\frac{1}{2} e^{-|x|}\;dx\;dy$
If $x > 0$ integral does not converge. If $x < 0$, $F_{\xi}(z) = \frac{1}{4} e^{2 + z} (-1 + e^2)$
Then we take the derivative and get the answer. Is everything all right?

Direct calculation is very boring. Denote $Y'=3-2Y$ which is uniform on $[-1,1]$ and let us compute first the density of $Z=X+Y'$, which is a symmetric rv. Therefore for  the density of $z$ is
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{4}\int_{-1}^1 e^{-|z-y|}dy.$$ For $-1<z<1$ we consider
$$I_1=\int_{-1}^z e^{-z+y'}dy'=1-e^{-1-z}$$
$$I_2=\int_{z}^1 e^{z-y'}dy'=1-e^{-1+z}$$giving $$f(z)=\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-1}\cosh z.)$$ For $z>1$ we have $$f(z)=\frac{1}{4}\int_{-1}^1 e^{-z+y'}dy'=e^{-z}\frac{1}{2}\sinh 1$$ and $f(z)=f(-z)$ of course. Finally the density $g(z')$ of $Z'=X-2Y=Z-3$ is $g(z')=f(z'+3).$

unfortunately, I don't understand where the factor $(z-y')$ in the product comes from. Are you using the convolution formula?

yes, of course!

Then, according to formula it should be $\frac{1}{4}\int_{-1}^1 e^{-|y'-z|}dy'$

Oh, you are right. I am editing. Apologies

I am not sure why we have $f(z)=f(-z)$, I calculated  for $z<-1$ and got $0.25 * e^{(-1 - z)} (-1 + e^2)$

Reasonably, Arthur, $f(z)=f(-z)$ since it is the density of the convolution of two symmetric probabilities. Your calculation has a little error, check.
